# Integrating a list of values

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

The data given here

```
data = Table[Clip[Sin[x], {0, 1}], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}]
```

generates the following curve

```
ListPlot[data]
```

I want to know, how to compute the integral of this curve using only the data given above.

Comment: If you only have a list of function values, you need to give the step size as well.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the stepsize is 0.1 as suggested by the construction of the Table, you can calculate:

```
0.1*Total[data]
```

to get the numerical integral. To visualize the integral and plot it you can ListPlot:

```
0.1*Accumulate[data]
```

Hence:

```
data = Table[Clip[Sin[x], {0, 1}], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
ListPlot[{data, 0.1*Accumulate[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How is the function Accumulate related to Integration?

Comment: As you are accumulating the data, you are integrating the function up to that point. So this is the answer to your statement that you "want the integral as a plot."

Comment: Thanks, @bill, it works nice. But looking at the definition of Accumulate[], it is not immediately clear how it should give an integral when multiplied by the stepsize. I mean given the definition Accumulate[i,j,k]=i,i+j,i+j+k, how does this lead to integration?

Comment: This is called the Rieman approximation to the integral.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. In a Rieman sum, nth term is not the sum of all (n-1) terms, which seems to be the case with Accumulate[]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: Each term in the Rieman sum is the area of the rectangle. The area is the height of the curve times the width of the box -- hence it is the value of the data at that point times the stepsize 0.1. When you integrate, you are adding up all the areas of all the boxes... hence accumulating the value.

Answer (score 3):

Using *Tai's method*:

```
ω = ConstantArray[0.1, Length[data]];
ω[[1]] *= 0.5;
ω[[-1]] *= 0.5;
ω.data
```

Alternatively

```
a = Table[{x, Clip[Sin[x], {0., 1.}]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
Integrate[Interpolation[a][x], {x, a[[1, 1]], a[[-1, 1]]}]
```

> 2.00038

Comment: For `Interpolation` you can also play with the `InterpolationOrder` option to increase the accuracy (sometimes). In this case it doesn't do much though.

Comment: Jepp. The reseason is the kink in the middle of the integral. This way, one cannot profit from higher order quadrature rules. Trapezoidal rule is almost optimal.

Comment: I want the integral as a plot, a curve. Any way of doing that?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) has not been mentioned yet, which is the result from a 2nd-order interpolation and will have a smaller error than that from a 1st-order one. So according to the formula, the inputs are the `List` of samples of the function `data` and the step size `h`:

```
simpsoncoefficients[n_] := SparseArray[{1 -> 1, -1 -> 1, i_?EvenQ -> 4}, n, 2]
integral[data_, h_] := (h/3) simpsoncoefficients[Length[#]].# &[data]
```

Then `integral[data, 0.1]` gives `2.00024`.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you want the integral *as a plot* in a comment; I wonder if the following is what you had in mind. Here I am using your definition of data, and assuming a $0.1$ step size, as hinted at by your `Table` expression.

```
tuples = Transpose@{Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1], data};

Show[
  Plot[
    NIntegrate[Interpolation[tuples][x], {x, 0, xmax}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"],
    {xmax, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"integral"}
  ],
  ListPlot[
    Style[tuples, Thick, ColorData[97][2]],
    Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.01]],
    PlotLegends -> {"data"}, Joined -> True
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]